# How to duplicate each row in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

| Metric 1 | Metric 2 | Stat 1 | Stat 2 | Other Val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 10 | 15 | 20 | Z |
| 3 | 6 | 9 | 12 | X |

I want to split each row into two, separated by metric, with all other columns remaining the same for both. For example:

| Metric 1 | Metric 2 | Stat 1 | Stat 2 | Other Val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | NaN | 15 | NaN | Z |
| NaN | 6 | NaN | 12 | X |
| 5 | NaN | 15 | NaN | Z |
| NaN | 6 | NaN | 12 | X |

My initial thought is to manually duplicate each row, and then set the metrics to NaN one by one, but I'm not sure if this is the best way. At the very least, how can I iterate over the dataframe and duplicate each row? I want to double each row with the copy appearing right below the original for each.

Comment: `Stat` also has `NaN` values in expected output. Is it based on columns that end in `1` and `2` etc or are there some other rules for the spacing?

Comment: Yes, It is simply based on the columns being named 1 and 2. I want one row to only have information about item #1, and then have a duplicate row that only has information about item #2. I want all columns that aren't labelled '1' or '2' to be the same across the original and the duplicate. Basically copy the row and set all the the '1' column to NaN, and then set all the '2' columns to NaN instead in the copy. I want to do this for each row.

Comment: does "Other Val" have any association on whether you want metric/stat 1 or 2? E.I should Z always be associated with metric/stat 1

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't really sure about the logic behind what values are needed.  So this doesn't match your output but maybe would get you moving in the direction you want to go:

```
df_list = []

for x in [2,1]:
    dfx = df.copy()
    dfx[dfx.filter(like=f' {x}').columns] = np.nan
    df_list.append(dfx)
    
pd.concat(df_list).sort_index()
```

Result:

```
   Metric 1   Metric 2   Stat 1   Stat 2  Other Val
0        5.0        NaN     15.0      NaN         Z
0        NaN       10.0      NaN     20.0         Z
1        3.0        NaN      9.0      NaN         X
1        NaN        6.0      NaN     12.0         X
```